# A make file for exporting all inkscape svg to pdf

Tags: makefile

I'm trying to write a make file that will create PDF from every inkscape SVG in a directory. From the make manual and various tutorials, it seems a pattern rule is the way to go, so I have

```
%.pdf : %.svg
        inkscape -A $*.pdf $*.svg
```

I know the inkscape command works if I do it manually. When I invoke make though, I get

```
$ make
make: *** No targets.  Stop.
```

Since the pdf files don't exist yet, I can't invoke `make *.pdf` and `make *.svg` won't match any targets. Also, I can't find a way to put an `all` target in that depends on the pattern.

One final problem; This is part of a large project, and I would like to invoke make in this directory recursively, but if `make` alone doesn't work, what target should I invoke recursively and how do I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your pattern is correct, but a pattern tells make how to build a target if you ask for one.  You still have to ask for it, and since you haven't that's why you get the "no targets" message.

If you want to find all the SVG files and convert them, you can use the wildcard function:

```
SVGFILES := $(wildcard *.svg)

all: $(SVGFILES:%.svg=%.pdf)

%.pdf : %.svg
        inkscape -A $*.pdf $*.svg
```

I don't quite understand your second question.  Once you have the above you can just use normal `$(MAKE)` (always use this, never `make`) in a parent makefile to build these files.

Comment: Thanks, this works. Just had to change %.png to $.pdf. And yes, now that make without arguments works, I can simply invoke `$(MAKE)`. Thank you.

Comment: One last thing; Ho do I specify this directory as a dependency of a target in the parent directory. I need the images to build before they are processed one directory above.